# FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory. Even though it exists

Tags: python

My code is currently very basic, as this is the start of my project. I run into this error which makes no sence. Here is the code:

```
import pygame 
import sys

def playsound():
 pygame.mixer.init()
 popsound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:\School\Computing\flap.wav')
 popsound.play()

print(playsound())
```

For some reason, this error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/School/Computing/NEA_Project.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(playsound())
  File "C:/School/Computing/NEA_Project.py", line 6, in playsound
    popsound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:\School\Computing\flap.wav')
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
```

However, if I pick a different file from the same directory, it works no problem. Anyone got a fix for this?

Comment: You are using back-slashes rather than forward-slashes, so you'll have to escape the back-slashes with additional back-slashes so that they aren't treated like escape sequences: `"C:\\School\\Computing\\flap.wav"`

Comment: If you want to stop backslashes from being treated as escape sequences inside the string, write an `r` (for "raw") before the quotes, for example: `r'C:\School\Computing\flap.wav'` . If you do not actually _need_ to use escape sequences (such as `\n` for newline) inside the string, using a raw string is often a tidier solution than proliferating double backslashes, particular with Windows path names, and certainly network shares that can end up with `"\\\\"` where the original has a double backslash already.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `\` to `\\`:

```
import pygame 
import sys

def playsound():
 pygame.mixer.init()
 popsound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:\\School\\Computing\\flap.wav')
 popsound.play()

print(playsound())
```

The reason you should do this is because,
in Python strings, **backslashes are special characters**, called escape characters. They are used in representing whitespace characters like tabs (`"\t"`), newlines (`"\n"`), and carriage returns (`"\r"`).

Prefixing a special character with `"\"` turns it into an ordinary character.

---

**You can avoid the trouble altogether by simply using forward slashes.**